# Android Studio Terminal ERROR:'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, terminal, keytool

I tried  to generate a Development Key Hash for my Facebook login. But the terminal on Android Studio gives me error saying

```
       "ERROR:'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"
```

My keytool.exe is in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin and my debug.keysore is in .android folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` to your PATH variable.
You can do it this way in windows console :

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
```

Comment: I Did in this way, but it didn't help :( Variable Name : JAVA_HOME
Variable Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

Variable Name : PATH 
Variable Value : %JAVA_HOME%\bin